# Lua ')' expected (to close '(' at line 19 near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

When trying to run the code below, this error is produced:

> lua/testhud.lua:28: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 19) near ''

Code:

```
surface.CreateFont( "Whatever", {

    font = "Arial", 
    size = 100,
    weight = 500,
    blursize = 0,
    scanlines = 0,
    antialias = true, 
    underline = false,
    italic = false,
    strikeout = false,
    symbol = false,
    rotary = false,
    shadow = false,
    additive = false,
    outline = false,
} )


hook.Add( "HudPaint" , "DrawMyHud" , function( )

    local health = LocalPlayer():Health()

    draw.RoundedBox(0,8,8,300+4 , 30+4,Color(86,55,89))
    draw.RoundedBox(0,10,10,health * 3,30,Color(255,120,120))
    draw.SimpleText(health.."%","Whatever",10 + 150 , 10 + 15 ,Colour(255,255,255),1,1)


end
```

Comment: This is a fairly easy to interpret error. Parenthesis should be matched. For every opening paren, there should be a closing paren. The error tells you Lua expected to find a closing paren and didn't, and it tells you exactly where the opening paren was (line 19). So you go to line 19, find an opening paren, then try to find the closing one that matches it. Doing this will lead you to Chris H's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Error: lua/testhud.lua:28: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 19) near ''

You are missing a ')' to close the '(' near the start of line 19. Presumably it should be after the 'end' statement of the function you're defining:

```
hook.Add( "HudPaint" , "DrawMyHud" , function() 

    local health = LocalPlayer():Health()

    draw.RoundedBox(0,8,8,300+4 , 30+4,Color(86,55,89))
    draw.RoundedBox(0,10,10,health * 3,30,Color(255,120,120))
    draw.SimpleText(health.."%","Whatever",10 + 150 , 10 + 15 ,Colour(255,255,255),1,1)

end )
```

Comment: I'll run it and see what it says.

Comment: Now it gave me the error code [ERROR] lua/testhud.lua:1: attempt to index global 'surface' (a nil value)
Put  if (SERVER) then end and if (CLIENT) then and leave it open?

Comment: Here you've used variables (like `surface` and `hook`) and called functions (like `CreateFont` and many more) without having defined them. So you get the message about attempting to index a nil value, because Lua doesn't know what those things are. Perhaps there's a module which you need to import with a `require` statement.

Comment: I hope it wouldn't be to much to ask for a video to give me a step by step basis of something like this. (It's been three years since I've done any lua coding and I've completely forgot everything)

Comment: Well that would be far too much to ask and frankly it's absurd that the idea entered your mind. If you've completely forgotten everything I suggest taking a look at the [Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/) or finding somewhere to buy or borrow a copy of [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/).

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't mean you make a video on a step by step tutorial on this, I was more or less meaning what you just gave me, my apologies for the confusion I do appreciate what you've given me. Question has been answered and I'm more than satisfied with the support I was given. Thank you.

Comment: I know GLua when I see it, This needs to be wrapped in an `if CLIENT then ... end`.